# Reading address of variable created in terminal

Tags: bash

Let's consider the following situation:

1. I've created variabel as follows: `my_var=32`
2. I can read its value as follows: `echo $my_var`
3. I want to read address of this variable, but I can't figure it out.

Is it possible to perform it?

Comment: What do you mean by "address" - location in memory? What do you want to do with that information? If it's not possible, maybe someone can suggest an alternative?

Comment: What do you mean with "Address". The shell does not expose such low level details to the user, does it?

Comment: Yes I mean location in memory. I am curious if it is possible, it's all.

Comment: I believe you can't do this with bash. What do you need it for?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to perform it?

Write a Bash builtin that will basically call [var_lookup()](https://github.com/mfragkoulis/bash/blob/master/variables.c#L1788) with the variable name and then print `SHELL_VAR` address, or address of [value](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3a35a2d601a55f337f8ca02a541f8c033682247/variables.h#L84).

You can also compile Bash with debugging symbols and inspect it with a debugger.

Comment: Cool! But I want to ask, why do you link that mirror? It looks outdated (last commit 19 Dec 2018) and customized ("provides an adapted version of GNU bash for use with the scatter-gather shell"). The canonical repo is [on GNU Savannah](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/).